# ReactJS on static content web

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, portfolio

I plan to learn react js library, but I have one important question:
Does it make sense to use react in webpage with static content (no database)? For example in simple web portfolio where content basically won't change over time (but there will be some animations)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. Amongst many benefits that it offers for a web application, if your application doesn't have to deal with complex state mutations, I don't see why you would incorporate in your application.

Where react shines is it is a diffing algorithm, that minimizes the number of mutations to the DOM, which is when I would use React. That shouldn't make you not want to learn it though, because it is one of the most popular front end libraries out there.

For static websites there exist tools like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) you might want to get into after your React journey :)